# Encountering Errors: CV2.Resize, Array.Sum

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am running the following codes and encountering the following error messages:

```
img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\WaWa\\Jupyter-Demo\\images\\hexagon.jpg')
img = np.pad(img, 200, mode='constant')
img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(1600, 1600), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
U0 = np.array(img).sum(axis=2).astype(float)
lam1 = 400*u.nm
lam2 = 500*u.nm
lam3 = 600*u.nm
lam4 = 700*u.nm

x = np.linspace(-2,2,U0.shape[0]) * u.mm
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, x)

U_new1 = compute_U(U0, xv, yv, lam=lam1, z=6*u.cm)
U_new2 = compute_U(U0, xv, yv, lam=lam2, z=6*u.cm)
U_new3 = compute_U(U0, xv, yv, lam=lam3, z=6*u.cm)
U_new4 = compute_U(U0, xv, yv, lam=lam4, z=6*u.cm) 

error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[37], line 6
       3 img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\William Yeung\\Jupyter-Demo\\images\\hexagon.jpg')
       5 img = np.pad(img, 200, mode='constant')
 ----> 6 img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(1600, 1600), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
       7 #U0 = np.array(img).sum(axis=2).astype(float)
       8 lam1 = 400*u.nm

error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'resize'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src data type = 17 is not supported
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'


AxisError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[38], line 7
      5 img = np.pad(img, 200, mode='constant')
      6 #img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(1600, 1600), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
----> 7 U0 = np.array(img).sum(axis=2).astype(float)
      8 lam1 = 400*u.nm
      9 lam2 = 500*u.nm

 File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:49, in _sum(a, axis, dtype, out, 
 keepdims, initial, where)
     47 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
     48          initial=_NoValue, where=True):
---> 49     return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)

AxisError: axis 2 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0
```

I am running Python 3.10 and as a newbie in Python cannot figure out the solutions. Your feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say anything without the image. Please post a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can tell, without the image, is that, by default, `imread` returns a BGR color image (even if the image is a grayscale one on the disk). So a 3D array (with shape (H,W,3), W×H being the resolution of the image).

And `np.pad` as used here, add 200 `0` to each side of each axis of the array. So 200 on the left, 200 on the right, 200 on top, 200 at bottom, **and 200 before B value, and 200 after R value**. So If your image is 1920×1080, `imread` returns a 1080×1920×3 array of numbers (blue, green, red component for each pixels). And after np.pad, you have a 1480×1320×403 array, including 400 0 for each pixels (including the real pixel, or the pad one) for 400 new unknown colors.

Open CV does handle images with 403 different color component. It handles just 1, 3, or 4 colors (graylevel, BGR/RGB, or BGRA/RGBA, with alpha/transparency component).

So, sure, resize doesn't know how to handle that 1420×1320×402 array, that, surely, isn't an image from opencv point of view.

But that answer is based on the fact that `img` is, indeed, a color image, aka a 3D-array. Which it is by default. If `img` was a black&

The next error you get seems to indicate otherwise. It seems to say that `img` is 2D-array (so a grayscale image. What you would get, if you had passed optional argument `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` to `imread`). In which case, `np.pad` should have done what you expected from it. And `cv2.resize` should have worked. And But then, indeed, the `.sum(axis=2)` cannot work on a 2D array.

So, what I see here are 2 contradictory errors.
If `img` is a BGR image (as it is if you really got it from this `imread`), then the first error is normal, and comes from your misuage of `np.pad`, but the second error shouldn't have happened.
If `img` is a grayscale image, a 2D array, the first error shouldn't happen, but the second should.

I also see, from what you posted that

1. You seem to have the habit to do things like `img=sometransformationof(img)`
2. You seem to use a notebook (you even tagged your question "jupyter-notebook", which, btw, is off-topic, since your question has nothing to do with notebooks. That would be like tagging "rolling chair" because you were sitting in one when you wrote the code. But, well, at least, it is a further proof that you are using a notebook, added to the `cell[1]` that appears in your copy of error message

When doing both (overloading what `img` is, with lines like `img=somefunc(img)`, and doing so in notebook), we often end up having `img` being not really what it is after the previous cell, but what it is after another cell execution, since, in a notebook, cells are not always executed in linear order (that the whole point of a notebook, after all)

So, the contradiction I see in your error messages may come from the fact that `img` isn't really, for the second message, what it is supposed to be after your `cv2.imread`, but rather what it is after one of your attempt to solve the `np.pad/np.resize` problem.

So, all that being said, you must choose:

- Either you work on 2D arrays (grayscale). And then your `np.pad` is ok, but suming along axis 2 makes no sense.
- Either you work on 3D arrays (color) images. And then, suming along axis 2 makes sense (it is one cheap way to transform the color image into a grayscale image, with a graylevel value between 0 and 255×3=765). But then you must pad only axis 0 and 1, not axis 2 (color components).

```py
paddedimg=np.pad(img, ((200,200), (200,200), (0,0)), mode='constant')
```

(meaning (200 on top, 200 at bottom), (200 on left, 200 on right), (no extra color component))

Comment: Coding points to the wrong location of file and resolved coding error. Thanks